# Hive jdbc connection is giving error if MR is involved

Tags: jdbc, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am working on Hive-jdbc connection in HDP 2.1

Code is working fine for queries where mapreduce is not involved like "select * from tabblename". The same code is showing error when the query is modified with a 'where' clause or if we specify columnnames(which will run mapreduce in the the background).

I have verified the correctness of the query by executing it in HiveCLI.
Also I have verified the read/write permissions for the table for the user through which I am running the java-jdbc code.

The error is as follows

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:275)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:355)
    at com.testing.poc.hivejava.HiveJDBCTest.main(HiveJDBCTest.java:25)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, running the same query through HiveCLI works but through the JDBC driver does not? And the HiveCLI query is also kicking off a MapReduce job?

Comment: Yes it is running mapreduce in the back and working fine

Answer (score 1):

Today I also got this exception when I submit a hive task from java.
The following error:

```
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriverorg.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriverhive_driver:
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriverhive_url:jdbc:hive2://10.174.242.28:10000/defaultget 
connection sessucess获取hive连接成功！
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

---

I tried to use the sql execute in hive and it works well. Then I saw the log in `/var/log/hive/hadoop-cmf-hive-HIVESERVER2-cloud000.log.out` then I found the reason of this error. The following error:

```
Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException(Permission denied: user=anonymous, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

---

### Solution

I used the following command :

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 777  /
```

---

This solved the error!

```
hive_driver:org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
hive_url:jdbc:hive2://cloud000:10000/default
get connection sessucess
获取hive连接成功！
Heart beat
执行insert成功！
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use beeline to execute the same queries, do you see the same behaviour as you get while running your test program?

The beeline client also uses the open source JDBC driver and connects to Hive server, which is similar to what you do in your program. HiveCLI on the other hand has Hive embedded in it and does not connect to a remote Hive server by default. You can use HiveCLI to connect to a remote Hive Server 1 but I don't believe you can use it to connect to Hive Server2 (use beeline for Hive Server 2).

For this error, you can take a look at the hive.log and hiveserver2.log on the server side to get more insight into what might have caused the MapReduce error.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Holman

Comment: By the way, Simba also provides JDBC and ODBC connectivity to Hive http://www.simba.com/connectors/apache-hadoop-hive-driver. You can try out the free trial version and get support to help with your POC.